# How best to catch missing let!, do!, return and return! in computation expressions in F#

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I love computation expressions, but I make simple mistakes like forgetting the return keyword or the ! on expressions like let! and return!, or I simply forget to write the do!. This happens much with state monads where I tend to forget about the state and just focus on the monadic operators I have defined.

I sometimes make sure my monadic operators return a type that is "of monad type" instead of an "anonymous" function. This helps to track my forgetful typing, yet is not really ideal. Anybody have better tricks?

Comment: Encapsulating state inside a monad type (instead of passing around plain functions) is standard practice, partly because it avoids this kind of error. What don't you like about this approach?

Comment: Your are right, I said "not ideal" but maybe there is no other way to make things implicitly wrong as soon as possible. I think I "kind of" like the "naked" functional type signature of the state monad. Yet wrapping it up ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Given a typical monad, your code shouldn't compile if you're missing a `!` after a keyword because the types won't work out.  For example:

```
let sum = async {
  let x = async { return 1 }
  let y = async { return 2 }
  return x + y
}
```

This won't compile because you're attempting to add two `Async<int>`s, but it will compile if you change the `let`s to `let!`s.

Similarly, to identify missing `return`s, just look out for compiler warning messages and odd monadic types:

```
let sum = async {
  let! x = async { return 1 }
  let! y = async { return 2 }
  x + y // warning FS0020
}
```

In this case, `sum` is an `Async<unit>`, which should be apparent when you try to use it elsewhere in your code.  Alternatively, you can use a type annotation to catch this problem immediately:

```
let sum : Async<int> = async { // error FS0001: type mismatch
  let! x = async { return 1 }
  let! y = async { return 2 }
  x + y // warning FS0020
}
```

Comment: Correct, omissions lead to compiler errors. But with codes like a monadic parser, the error is not always obviously tied to the ommision. For example forgetting the ! on return!, returns well but not what you want.

Comment: @user519985 - adding a type annotation should catch cases where you use `return` instead of `return!`.